# Trigger to delete row from another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have two tables which is FORUM and COMMENTS

FORUM PRIMARY KEY: FORUMID

COMMENTS FOREIGN KEY: FORUMID

and when the user would like to delete any row in forum, it must execute the trigger and delete the comments in that forum first

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trg_delete_comments
BEFORE DELETE ON forum
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
   v_forumID varchar(14);
   v_user    varchar(20);
BEGIN
   select forumID into v_forumID
   from forum
   where forumID =:OLD.forumID;

   DELETE COMMENTS
   WHERE FORUMID = v_forumID;
END;
/
```

When I try to execute this trigger, I get the error of "ORA-04091: table FORUM is mutating, trigger/function may not see it". Is there any way to solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using two queries for this.  The logic appears to be:

```
BEGIN
   DELETE COMMENTS
   WHERE FORUMID = :OLD.forumID;
END;
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I think I have duplicated the same action twice. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a functionality that can be easily provided through a foreign key constraint. You can configure a constraint with the `on delete cascade` clause so that when a parent record is deleted, children are deleted too.

Consider [the following example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a088c70259fd66c3b2ecf8994f199083):

```
create table forums (
    forum_id int primary key,
    user_id int
);

create table comments (
    comment_id int primary key,
    forum_id int,
    constraint fk_comments_forum 
        foreign key (forum_id) 
        references forums(forum_id)
        on delete cascade
);

select * from forums;
```

```
FORUM_ID | USER_ID
-------: | ------:
       1 |       1
       2 |       2
```

```
select * from comments;
```

```
COMMENT_ID | FORUM_ID
---------: | -------:
         1 |        1
         2 |        1
         3 |        2
```

```
delete from forums where forum_id = 1;
1 rows affected

select * from comments;
```

```
COMMENT_ID | FORUM_ID
---------: | -------:
         3 |        2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this into AFTER STATEMENT trigger and then can delete the rows -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger trg_delete_comments
AFTER DELETE ON forum
BEGIN

   DELETE COMMENTS
   WHERE FORUMID IN (select forumID
                     from forum
                     where forumID = :OLD.forumID);
END;
/
```

Comment: The above after statement will not work. The columns Old.column_name not New.column_name are NOT available in statement level triggers. A compound trigger or if not available on your version a package to simulate a compound  trigger. But still cascade on FK still much easier option than either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be reinventing the wheel here. You could simply have your foreign key defined as `on delete cascade`, and let the database do the heavy lifting for you:

```sql
ALTER TABLE comments
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_forum
FOREIGN KEY (forumid)
REFERENCES forum(forumid)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```